# Updating Ubuntu 11.04 to 12.04 preferrably through command line

Tags: linux, command-line, installation, command-line-arguments, updates

I am attempting to update my Ubuntu Natty Narwhal (11.04) to Precise Pangolin (12.04). When I checked the Update Manager, I was told I couldn't do that. I had to get to 11.10 first, if I want it safely. Sounds like a plan.

And so I've ran through the Update Manager who keeps giving me 404 on the "Setting New Software Channels" like this:

```
W:Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric-security/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
```

And there wre a lot of that!

No, I do not want the latest Ubuntu yet, though. Not even Lubuntu. Please, I just want to find out how to download a specific version of the package, or if it's even possible. I kinda imagine a command-line text where I can attach the URL of the Ubuntu distribution I want. And then update the one I have.

I know both Natty and Precise are EOL distributions, so I understand it would be difficult.

Thank you folks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the hardware specific package of ubuntu 12.04 directly

http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/
or
http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-install-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin

There is no such option in the standard installation medium.

Comment: Thanks, sir. It was a long shot for me. :)